# Adding glows to Stage3D objects

Tags: actionscript-3, stage3d, agal

I'm making a Stage3D space game: www.sugarspook.com/darkmatters/demo.html,
and I'd like to add 'glows' to some objects.

Is there a way to do this solely in the AGAL shaders, or do I need to pre-render the glowing objects and 'blur' them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you will need to prerender to a texture first. Here's what i would do:

- Prerender an object to texture.
- Downsample multiple times to a desired size (more downsamples = bigger glow).
- Apply some kind of blur (I prefer Gaussian).
- Tint blurred texture with some color.
- Upsample.
- Render.

You can [take a look](http://nekobit.puslapiai.lt/outer-glow-for-alternativa3d/) at the example I posted in my blog. It's for Alternativa3D but may be useful as the principle is the same everywhere. Here's [github link](https://github.com/Varnius/Alternativa3DCustomMaterials) to whole lib.

Comment: OK, well I guess the next thing is to figure out HOW to do what you suggest. Downsampling hadn't occurred to me. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Check out my blog post. There is a link to a git repository where you can find some source for this.

Comment: I can't seem to find the link to github, sorry. I can find the demo. Looks good. Any pointers?

Comment: Added github link to my answer. Check eu.nekobit.alternativa3d.post.effects.OuterGlow class. :)